# Rest api of gerrit gives the response but Python-gerrit-api package for fetching revisions gives status 404

Tags: python, gerrit

**Documentation:** https://python-gerrit-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

**Code**

gerrit = GerritClient(base_url="https://gerrit.xx.com",username='xxx',password='xxx')

change = gerrit.changes.get("xxx")

ab=change.get_revision("32423")

print(ab.get_commit().list_change_files())

**Question**

For some endpoints, I am able to send get responses from the rest api but via this package I get this error(gerrit.utils.exceptions.NotFoundError: 404 Client Error). I am able to get response from Get Rest api for this url: gerrit.xx.xx.com/a/projects/xxxx/commits/xxxx/files via postman. But error with above code.

Comment: Is your project a top level or sub level project? parentA/childB or just parentA

Comment: @Naga sai Kiran, if you append `/a/` to the `base_url=` param, is the behavior the same? Some endpoints might require it to access data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is a bug, I have fixed it and made a pull request. See: https://github.com/shijl0925/python-gerrit-api/pull/5